# iOS: How to stop the device standby timer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm creating an iOS app who will have to stop the standby timer.

I mean the timer who put the device in standby after 60 seconds that a user does not touch the screen.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try to set `UIApplication`'s `idleTimerDisabled` property to `YES`.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Answer (score -3):

you can also put this line of code and it should work also.

```
[application setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: your variable "application" is not defined as a UIApplication, and needs to be initialised as [UIApplication sharedApplication]