# batch uploads and downloads - iOS Google Drive SDK

Tags: ios, file-upload, download, google-drive-api

I have successfully integrated Google Drive iOS SDK in my app and I'm able to upload and download files onto Google drive through my app.

Problem is when I'm uploading or downloading a large file (above 100 MB). **Device goes to sleep** if there's no user interaction for some time and when that happens, the download or upload stops. Or **if app goes into background, the upload or download does not continue.. and there is no error message**..

I did google for this issue.. I was trying **Background Transfer Service** introduced in iOS 7, it seems that, when using Google drive SKD, we have to use their classes or client libraries for uploads and downloads (**GTMHTTPFetcher** in this case).

Can anybody please point me to any notes or links for weather I can use batch uploads and downloads with Google Drive API's....??

Anybody integrated **Background Transfer Service with iOS Google Drive SDK** will also do for me right now..

I need some pointers..

Any help would be apriciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I dont know if you solved this but once suggestion, you can stop the phone to going into stanby mode. Check out this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064332/ios-how-to-stop-the-device-standby-timer